# Using a bash alias or function with environment variables on multiple lines

Tags: bash, alias

I have an alias in my bash_profile that is currently one really long line like this:

```
alias staging_server='MY_ENV1="http://example.com" MY_ENV2="http://example2.com" MY_ENV3="http://example3.com" MY_ENV4="http://example4.com" start_server -p 1234'
```

Is there a way to split this up with newlines using a function or alias to make it more legible? Something like this (which doesn't seem to work)?

```
alias staging_server=' \
  MY_ENV1="http://example.com" \
  MY_ENV2="http://example2.com" \
  MY_ENV3="http://example3.com" \
  MY_ENV4="http://example4.com" \
  start_server -p 1234
'
```

I'd like to avoid exporting these as I don't want them as the defaults.

Comment: Works for me; how does it not work for you?

Comment: `alias foo=' \ (ENTER)
  E1=1 \ (ENTER)
  E2=2 \ (ENTER)
env | grep ^E.= (ENTER)
'
`

Comment: Just use a function

Comment: So, it turns out this was all just an issue with some Tmux weirdness. I'm not really sure what was happening, but the alias started working after I killed my session (yes, I was `source`ing the whole time, it just wasn't doing anything I guess). Still, I ended up using a function anyway, so I'm glad I asked, thanks everyone! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The alias actually seems to work for me like that (provided that there's no whitespace after the backslashes). But a function might be nicer and at least makes it easier to use single-quotes:

```
staging_server() {
    MY_ENV1='http://example.com' \
    MY_ENV2="..." \
    start_server -p 1234 "$@"
}
```

Comment: Why  the backslashes in the function body?

Comment: @Dani_l, because they didn't want to export the variables. that's the same difference as between `FOO=blah somecmd` and `FOO=blah; somecmd`.

Comment: Put the body of the function in `(...)` rather than in `{...;}` to make the variables local (regarding @Dani_l's comment).

Answer (score 13):

Note that *exporting* would be fine (would not affect the rest of the shell session) if you did it in a subshell like:

```
staging_server() ( # <-- note the ( instead of { here.
  set -o allexport
  MY_ENV1="http://example.com"
  MY_ENV2="http://example2.com"
  MY_ENV3="http://example3.com"
  MY_ENV4="http://example4.com"
  exec start_server -p 1234 "$@"
)
```

Note that it doesn't imply an additional fork, we're just doing the fork earlier here.

The only case where that would imply an additional fork would be if you used a shell builtin in place `start_server` there (in which case in some shells like `bash` (one of those shells where that `exec` is needed as it's not done implicitly), using `exec` would *not* call that shell builtin).

Answer (score 3):

If you need *environment* variables, you can use the `env` command:

```
alias staging_server='env \
  MY_ENV1="http://example.com" \
  MY_ENV2="http://example2.com" \
  MY_ENV3="http://example3.com" \
  MY_ENV4="http://example4.com" \
  start_server -p 1234
'
```

Comment: Why not just use `alias comm='MY_ENV="abc" \comm'`?